# Split the column to multiple column based on the three diff categories--new scenario

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image]
data need to get split from SOID column to Circ,Language,Words as show above in pic. When trying with below logic :-

```
SELECT SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
 --regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit",
 --regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Language\\(s\\):\\s([a-zA-Z0-9, ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Language",
 regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 \\[\\] \\& ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circ", 
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Language[()s]*:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\, ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Language",
 regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Words:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Words"
FROM XYZ;
```

the data is getting handled correctly, But as per the pic highlighted in red some data is not getting captured with the above logic. Instead of showing all languages it is picking only one language as English,where as I need the output as all the languages which are in column. Please need your inputs.

Comment: Does `Words` always come after `Language`? Is the data you are after _always_ between `Language` and `Words`?

Comment: yes, the language is always before the words

Comment: Simon, I don't think so. The previous question was a simpler version and already answered correctly. This one is different cause as I see, Naveen noticed a different format on languages.

Comment: Sorry for duplicating, that was answered correctly by Atil, since i found new scenarios, i just made another question instead of making existing one complicated.

Comment: Okay no worries. I thought, since the titles and content were really similar it was the same scenario.

Comment: If the data you are after is always between Language and Words, then just cook up REGEX that pulls it out on that basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems things are getting complicated. To handle this new format, you need to do some changes on how to extract languages.

Instead of using one simple regexp_substr, I used two. One is for handling "Language(s): xxxx" and the other one is to handle "Language: x,y,z" (including single language), and combine them using NVL.

```
with XYZ as (
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North America, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North America, Language: English, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North America, Language(s): English,Spanish, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION                                                   
  union all
  select 'Attachments: 1, Circuit: North America, Language: English, Language: Dutch, Language: German, Words: 400' as SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
)                                                  
SELECT 
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 \\[\\]]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit", 
NVL( regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Language\\(s\\):\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\, ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e'), 
REGEXP_REPLACE( regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, '(Language:.*), Words', 1, 1, 'e'), '[ ]*Language: '  )) AS "LanguageString"
FROM XYZ;


+---------------+----------------------+
|    Circuit    |    LanguageString    |
+---------------+----------------------+
| North America | English,Dutch        |
| North America | English              |
| North America | English,Spanish      |
| North America | English,Dutch,German |
+---------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Atil, its working fine.  I found an other cause for circuit, with the below expression it is handling correclty. 
regexp_substr(SALES_ORDER_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'Circuit:\\s([a-zA-Z0-9 \\[\\] \\& ]+)(,\\s|$)', 1, 1, 'e') AS "Circuit", 
Attachment(s): 2, Circuit: International Financial Wire (self-service), Language(s): English,Dutch, Words: 357' this scenario not getting handled in circuit.